# Oracle: Pattern for to_char(number) to add additional ascii characters?

Tags: oracle, formatting, numbers, ascii, oracle-apex

Using the Oracle to_char(number) function, is it possible to append ascii characters to the returned string?

Specifically, I need to add a percentage character to the returned string.

"select to_char(89.2244, '999G999G999G999G990D00') from dual" -->
returns "89.22". I need a format pattern that returns "89.22%".

I am using this through reports in Application Express, so cannot simply concatenate "%" to the query, i need to put it in the number format.

Comment: You are expecting some enormous percentages - thirteen orders of magnitude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can't wrap the to_char with a CONCAT?

```
select concat(to_char(89.2244, '999G999G999G999G990D00'),'%') from dual
```

Comment: No, sadly not. In Apex reports, you only specify which number format to use, and the to_char-formatting is done "behind the scenes" in compiled pl/sql, so my only option it to use a number format (or make a css hack)

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this with just the number format string. CSS might be the way to go here.

Comment: You could use a view instead of a table, and do any kind of selection manipulation in the view. Not sure if that is preferrable...

Comment: Using a view or selecting the number column as a concatenated string would do, but that rules out automatic summary operations from the tool. Will use CSS, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it right in the number format.

If you are able to change `NLS_CURRENCY` for you session, you can do the following:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(1.2, '999G999G999G999G990D00L' /*, 'NLS_CURRENCY=%' */)
FROM    dual

--- 
1,20%
```

Comment: Thank you, i guess i only needed to be certain that it is not possible to do it in the number format directly. I will use some kind of html/css hack instead.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty way:

select to_char(89.2244, '999G999G999G999G990D00L', 'NLS_CURRENCY=''%''') from dual;

Answer (score 0):

```
SYS @ orant11g >select to_char(89.2244, '999G999G999G999G990D00')||'%' from dual;
```

> ```
> TO_CHAR(89.2244,'999G999
> ------------------------
>               89.22%
> ```

Just use the || bars instead of the concat function.